# Struts redirect from model

Tags: model-view-controller, jboss, struts

I'm trying to implement a security model where the model of secured pages inherits from a SecureSupport. I don't know how or if I can redirect from a constructor, however. See below:

```
public class SecureSupport extends ActionSupport {
    private Map session;

    public SecureSupport  throws Exception
    {
        session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();

        if(!session.containsKey("User"))
        {
            // redirect from here
        }
        return SUCCESS;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your own exception (ie NoUserException) which has to be a run time exception. Then catch this exception with global exception handler, there you can redirect anywhere you want.